# Do not proceed until common menu has finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a common menu that I am including in all my HTML. Some menu items are set to "disabled" by default as they can only be accessed from certain pages. When one of the allowed pages is displayed I remove the disabled class. Sometimes the removal of the disabled class does not happen and the user sees a red circle with a line through it. I have tried "holdReady" and "(window).load", and they do not work.

If I put an alert before removing the class it works.

The code is:

```
//$.holdReady( true );
////Include the menu before the document is ready.
//$("#includedContent").load("Menu.html");
//$.holdReady( false );

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Include the menu before the document is ready.
    $("#includedContent").load("Menu.html");    
});

//$(window).load(function(){

$(document).ready(function(){

    //Allow these items to be selected when a youth member is displayed 
    $("li").removeClass("disabled");
```

Comment: you should wait for load to complete.remove class inside load complete callback .see the doc http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.load()` signature has a callback function. `$.holdReady()` in not necessary in this case. You can set the `context` of `jQuery(selector. context)` to the element `.load()` is called on, which is `this` within `.load()` callback function, to selector only `"li"` that are children of element having `id` "includedContent"`

```
$(function() {
  $("#includedContent").load("Menu.html", function() {
    // do stuff
    $("li", this).removeClass("disabled");
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

document.ready and window.load are the two elements you need here.

document.ready : This is used when to load the DOM element and in the preset situation we need window.load which is used to be executed after loading the entire page .

Happy Coding